# How does "author" attribute in the "link" tag actually works?

Tags: html, meta-tags, author

I have read a few articles on the subject but i was not too happy with the information.

What do you write in the href attribute and how do search engines use the information? Does any other search engine use this info besidea google?

Answer (score 2):

**The main purpose of `rel=author`** :

To establish a relationship between a document and an author document.

**Where is it used?**

It may be used on any webpage where the author wants to be credited for authorship.

Example: This post was written.. by this person.

**Results?**

- The author's profile photo may appear in Google search engine results
- Search engine may increase the page rank based on credibility of the author

**Implementations:**

`<link rel="author"/>` - in meta data inside `<head>` section of the document/page.

`<a rel="author">` - link to authors page

`<a rel="author">` - link to authors social page